# Определение мобильной темы в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-plugin, wp-theme

Есть плагин WP Mobile Detect, через него можно вставлять шорткоды, а также их можно вставлять в тему: wpmd_is_notphone(), wpmd_is_phone() и другие.

Как сделать так чтобы он определял тему? По принципу такой конструкции или другой:

```
if( wpmd_is_notphone() ){ Тема A }
if( wpmd_is_phone() ){ Тема B }
else{ Тема B }
```

Comment: Согласно описанному алгоритму, вы хотите не определять тему, а установить ее динамически. Ничего не выйдет. В WordPress так нельзя.

Comment: Наверное придется склеить 2 темы в одну и использовать такую конструкцию при верстке
<?php if ( wpmd_is_notphone() ) : ?>
        <p>Desctop & tablet</p>

     <?php if ( wpmd_is_phone() ) : ?>
        <p>Phone</p>

     <?php else : ?>
        <p>Phone</p>
 <?php endif; ?>

Comment: В современных темах так не поступают. Делают адаптивную верстку и переключают стили с помощью @media. Фактически, тема реагирует на ширину экрана: до 767 мобилка, 768-1024 планшет, выше десктоп, возможно, с изменениями на 1200px и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать так чтобы он определял тему?

Что бы [этот древний плагин](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mobile-detect/) менял тему - боюсь нереально.. Ну минимум нецелесообразно. Для этого есть другие плагины. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/any-mobile-theme-switcher/screenshots/

Comment: Перепробовал кучу таких плагинов-переключателей, но они ужас как не дружат с плагином Супер Кэш. А этот древний четко все определяет, только список новых моделей телефонов и планшетовобновлять иногда нужно + можно адаптировать контент записей.

Comment: Настраивать кеш-плаги нужно или удалять нафик. Или вообще использовать современную, адаптивную тему

Comment: @Юра, а плагин W3 Total Cache тоже не дружит? Попробуйте, он прекрасно себя показал в работе